# Proving a equilateral triangle is equiangular

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

How do you prove a triangle is equiangular with 5 steps?
All I know is that triangle abc is equilateral? I need to prove it with a 2 column proof.

These are my statements and reasons....

Statements.                         Reasons

1.) ABC is equilateral             1.) Given

2.) BC = AC.                         2.) ?

3.) Angle A is congruent to B.         3.) ?      And B is congruent to C

4.) Angle A is congruent to Angle C.      4.) ?

5.)ABC is equiangular.                   5.) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. If you need a formal "two column" proof:

The reason for step 2 is that it's given - it follows from the definition of equilateral.

The reason for 3) and 4) is Euclid Proposition I.4
https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/guide2.html

The reason for 5) is the transitivity of "equals".

Comment: So what would the 3rd and the 4th step be called?

Comment: And the 5th step?

Comment: I don't understand your two questions. My answer tells you the reasons for steps 3,4 and 5. They're not "called" anything else.